# Extracting information From a ListView (C#)

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8

I'm currently working on a Windows Phone 8.1 project and I've run into some difficulty with ListView. I have defined the following Listview using C#:

```
        ListView addList = new ListView();
        //More addList definition.
        toAddGrid.Children.Add(addList);
```

I am then adding to this a StackPanel containing two textBoxes each time the user presses a menu button, like this:

```
        TextBox fieldEntry = new TextBox();
        fieldEntry.PlaceholderText = "Field Name";
        //more fieldEntry definiton            


        TextBox detailsEntry = new TextBox();
        detailsEntry.PlaceholderText = "Details";
        //More detailsEntry definiton


        StackPanel stackPan = new StackPanel();
        //More stackPanel definiton
        fieldCounter++;


       stackPan.Children.Add(detailsEntry);
       stackPan.Children.Add(fieldEntry);


       addList.Items.Add(stackPan);
```

Basically, I am having trouble retrieving the information from the textBoxes in each "stackPan" within the "addList". I would like to be able to get entered Strings and use them to create an object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Will this work?

```
foreach (StackPanel panel in addList.Items)
{
    foreach (TextBox box in panel.Children)
    {
        string text = box.Text;
    }
```